# Angular 2 input rage min variadic

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, input, min

So I have this issue:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" >  
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="number" formControlName="number" min="{{ FinalPaymentPrice}}"/> // This FinalPaymentPrice is a number which I get and whant to set. For example 2 and then 14 and so on
</form>
```

Based on that FinalPaymentPrice number for example: 4 user isn't allowed to enter 3 or less, but is allowed to enter 5 and more. And a validator for this:

```
export class PaymentComponent {
    myForm = new FormGroup({
        'number': new FormControl(null, [
            Validators.required
        ])
    });
```

The thing is my min input is variadic. The idea is that you get some price and you can't enter less only higher price. So if I do like this function works, but that's not right.

```
export class PaymentComponent {
    myForm = new FormGroup({
        'number': new FormControl(null, [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.min(2)
        ])
    });
```

I'm very new to Angular

Comment: I think you made mistake on 'number' is string if you are using form Controls are not in signal quote

Comment: It was on purpose, because it adds currency and other symbols

Answer (score 3):

**You can update validators on any event this way :**

```
this.myForm.controls['number'].setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.min(this.x)]);
this.myForm.get('number').updateValueAndValidity();
```

And **this.x** can vary as you want but an event has to update the validators of your control each time your x vary

**You can clean validators this way**

```
this.myForm.get('number').clearValidators();
this.myForm.get('number').updateValueAndValidity();
```

**Example**

Here an example of static variation of validator : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ate6tg

But you can vary the min value validator more dynamically (ie with a subscription)

Happy coding !

Comment: Oh... Where should I put this? Into ` myForm = new FormGroup({ ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is work fine
HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="number" formControlName="number"/>
    <pre>{{myForm.status | json}}</pre>
  </form>
```

ts:

```
this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      number: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(2)
      ])
    });
```

Comment: Not what I am looking for sir. I will edit question so to clarify what I mean

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your problem correctly, in your case, the min input value should be 2.

In that case you should make the input type as **number** instead of **text**.

i.e, `<input type="number" />` instead of `<input type="text" />`

Comment: This answer was for the question before modified where it has 2 as the hard coded minimum value.

Comment: No you understood wrong. I edited the issue for more clarity.